# Detect closed connection on non blocking socket

Tags: c, sockets, io

I'm really sorry if my question is a duplicate, but I didn't find useful infos in the site.

I'm using non blocking sockets and a select(). How can I detect if a client closed the connection on non-blocking socket? I saw that a read() returns -1 with errno = EWOULDBLOCK when no datas are available to be read and also when a connection is closed.

How can I discriminate above cases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the peer has closed the connection:

1. `select()` will return the socket as readable.
2. A `recv()` or `read()` on the socket will return zero.

> I saw that a read() returns -1 with errno = EWOULDBLOCK when no datas are available to be read

Correct, but the connection isn't closed.

> and also when a connection is closed.

No you didn't. That's not correct. It returns zero.

> How can I discriminate above cases?

They aren't the same, and they don't manifest themselves in the same way.

Comment: You are right! I've just made a toy client - server app and it works as you and alk explained. In my original app I'm collecting connections from browser, and I've seen that one thread is created to get each image from the server. Is it possible that when a thread got the image it do not close the socket/connection?

Comment: Yes, that's the effect of HTTP keep-alive. But if you're sending, you don't need to worry about what happens when receivng. Just close the socket when you've sent the image.

Comment: nope, my app is in the middle between server side and client side. It works like a forwarder, that is, it must collect datas arriving from one side then forward them to the other side. My forwarder app should be able to detect when a client closes the connection, because I need to close useless sockets and useless threads (I mean, threads that finished their jobs).

So, if I'm using HTTP keep-alive, is there no way to detect the end of thread's job?

Comment: SOLUTION: in persistent connections, after a certain amount of time, read() returns 0, so it is possible to detect the closed connection.

Comment: @LucaForte 'After a certain period of time' has nothing to do with it whatsoever. `read()` returns zero when the peer has closed the connection, which might be after a second or a year or a century.

Answer (score 4):

When the peer had closed the connection for a specific socket, a call to [`read()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) on this socket would return `0`. This behaviour is independent from the socket's blocking state.

From [`man 2 read`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) (*italics* by me):

> RETURN VALUE
>
> On success, the number of bytes read is returned (*zero indicates end of file*)

Comment: *Any* call returns zero. If the first call returned zero it would indicate the very unusual case of the peer closing without sending anything. And once a zero has been returned it will continue to be returned.

Comment: Removed the strikeout. Nobody cares about prior errors, and if they do they are available in the edit history.

Comment: @EJP: Thanks, I just left it in to avoid a dangling comment. :-) So let's clean up the comments ...