# I'm Trying find a way to let my server socket open till the connected client send all the messages he wants

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, serversocket, tclientsocket

The function `CreationFichier` I'm trying to make, should create a text document for each message the client send to the server, so that the messages get stocked, and be disposable for the reuse.
The thread function `mess` is the mechanism used to make the client/server sockets communicate between them. Now I'm struggling on finding a way to let my server socket open until the connected client send all the messages he wants, because the client should send 5 messages before it closes it's socket.

```
void CreationFichier(char * a){
// creating file pointer to work with files
    FILE *fptr;
// opening file in writing mode
    fptr = fopen("tp.txt", "w");
// exiting program 
    if (fptr == NULL) {
        printf("Error!");
        exit(1);
    }
    fprintf(fptr, "%s", a);
    fclose(fptr);;
}
//this is the thread protocol 
void * mess (void * arg){
    int so=*((int *)arg);
    char *mess="Bonjour";
    send(so,mess,strlen(mess)*sizeof(char),0);
    cha buff[100];
    int recu=recv(so,buff,99*sizeof(char),0);
    buff[recu]='\0';
    printf("Recu : %s\n",buff);
    if(strcmp(buff,"PUT")==0){
        CreationFichier(buff);
    }else if(strcmp(buff,"GET")==0){

    }
    free(arg);
    close(so);
}
int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    if(argc!=2){
        printf("Erreur il faut fournir un numero de port");
        return 0;
    }
    int p=atoi(argv[1]);
    int sock=socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    struct sockaddr_in adress_sock;
    adress_sock.sin_family=AF_INET;
    adress_sock.sin_port=htons(p);
    adress_sock.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    int r=bind(sock,(struct sockaddr*)&adress_sock,
    sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    if(r=0){
        r=listen(sockk,0);
        while(1){
            struct sockaddr_in caller;
            socklen_t size=sizeof(caller); 
            int *sock2=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
            *sock2=accept(sock,(struct sockaaddr *)&caller,&size)
            if(*sock2>0){
                printf("Nouvelle connection");
                pthread_t th;
                int r2=pthread_create(&th,NULL,mess,sock2);
                if(r2!=0){
                    printf("Probleme de creation de thread");
                    exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }else {
        printf("Probleme de Bind !")
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: `buff=="GET"` isn't going to happen in C. You need `strncmp()`.

Comment: @tadman I thank you for your answer it was helpfull , is just that it was my first post in Stackoverflow , so I kinda ignored the rules ,

Comment: @JadissElantaki Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30138638/detect-closed-connection-on-non-blocking-socket) help you? You can detect when the client has closed the connection and take appropriate actions.

Comment: What is the problem? We cannot see how you open and close the socket. Your server cannot force a client to send a certain amount, BTW. -- OT: I _love_ the abbreviation of "message" to "mess", because this is a mess (chaos). ;-)

Comment: We can see _how you_ _close the socket_ at the end of `mess`; _a way to let my server socket open_ is of course to not close it.

Comment: I was thinking on posting only the part that's related to the mess protocole I m editing the code adding the server code